# Making option "selected" with inline condition replaces whole string

Tags: php, html

I am trying to set an option as `selected` depending on the value of a PHP variable. When I try the following:

`<option value="mortgage" '.(isset($ppr['loan_type'])) && $ppr['loan_type'] == 'mortgage' ? "selected" : NULL.'>Mortgage</option>` it replaces the whole page with just the word 'selected'

Worth mentioning, all of the html is in a string because it will be rendered dynamically.

Comment: Wrap the entire ternary in parenthesis and I bet it fixes it

Comment: You are absolutely right, thank you.